# Refresh Kendo grid, selectbox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I have a Kendo grid that has a selectbox on each row.

When I perform an update action on a row, in the database the data for the row is updated and the data for the selectbox is updated. Then I run a dataSource.read() on the grid to refresh the screen. However, even though the row refreshes, the data in the selectbox does not.

So the question is, how do I tell Kendo grid to refresh the data in the selectbox?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dataSource.sync();` for manually refresh the dropdownlist.

```
var dataSource=new kendo.data.DataSource({
// Datasource Code with Parameter
});
var grid = JQuery("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource:dataSource,
});

jQuery('#changeevent').change(function()
     {
             dataSource.read({
                parametername:jQuery("#valueoffeild").val()
             });

             var grid = jQuery("#grid").data("kendoGrid")
         grid.refresh();
     });
```

Comment: Hi
I don't see any mention of dataSource.sync() in the code you posted (?) I also just tried using dataSource.sync() instead of dataSource.read() in case that was what you meant, but still the selectbox doesn't refresh.

Comment: Set datasource property as `autoSync: true`

Comment: Hi again. I tried that (following this example, "Example - enable auto sync" http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource). No success. :-(